# Tika: MIME-Type detection of Js, Css

Tags: mime-types, apache-tika

I use Apache Tika to extract text of all kind of files. Now I also want to use it to detect the correct MIME-type of a file.

This works for example for...

- PDF-Files (`application/pdf`)
- HTML-Files (`text/html`)

...but not for:

- CSS-Files (`text/plain` instead of `text/css`)
- Javascript-files (`text/plain` instead of `text/javascript`)
- ...

(These Mime-type-results come from my application and also from the tika-app).

I need for my application an exact MIME-type like `text/css` instead of the general `text/plain`. Is this possible with Tika?

Comment: Are you supplying the filename as a hint to Tika?

Comment: Yes, my application and the tika-app use `Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY` to set the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things. Firstly, you need to supply the filename to Tika, so it can use that to help specialise the plain text type into the appropriate subtype (CSS, JS etc). Secondly, you need to make sure you're using a new enough version of Tika.

I've just tried with the latest version of Tika, and with passing the filename in, and it can detect JS and CSS files just fine:

```
$ java -jar tika-app-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar --detect testCSS.css 
text/css

$ java -jar tika-app-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar --detect testJS.js
application/javascript
```

Also, the latest version of Tika (as of r1400795) has a unit test that automatically verifies that JS and CSS detection work, so you can be doubly sure it works fine!

Comment: Ok, you are right, the output of the `DefaultDetector` is correct, even with the older release tika 1.2. I have used the `AutoDetectParser`, there the content-type seems to be always `text/plain` for CSS-files.